# Spanish character encoding - iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, encoding

I am sending text from iphone to the server for processing.
The text contain some spanish characters  eg, á é í ó ú ü ñ ¿ ¡ ºª

While sending, I am encoding it with NSUTF8StringEncoding
Server side is also using UTF8 encoding to decode it.

But the server side decodes it as ???????

Please let me know if anyone has faced this issue and how this was resolved ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you confirm that the individual bytes received by the server are the same and in the same order? What are their hex values?

Comment: I will post the hex values. Need some time since server side is not handled by me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

Since this is a post data I had to escape the special characters.

`stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` doesn't seem to escape all the special characters. I faced this issue with "+" character where it was getting replaced by a whitespace.

I feel same thing happens with spanish character where it is not escaped properly, so I manually replaced it and it worked.

following is an example. I wrote this for all the characters

```
escapedString = [escapedString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"À" withString:@"%C0"];        
        escapedString = [escapedString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Á" withString:@"%C1"];        
        escapedString = [escapedString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Â" withString:@"%C2"];        
        escapedString = [escapedString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Ã" withString:@"%C3"];        
        escapedString = [escapedString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Ä" withString:@"%C4"];
```

Thank you xj1200 and saadnib for looking in to this. I really appreciate. If you guys find any other better solution please post.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Google Toolbox for Mac for ancoding these characters. See files GTMNSString+

http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/source/browse/trunk/?r=27#trunk%2FFoundation

Comment: Please post the reason if you are down voting.

Comment: Because NSUTF8StringEncoding is perfectly adequate for encoding characters. The problem relates to receiving characters encoded using this format. There is no need to add complexity with third party APIs when the Foundation framework has everything necessary already.

Comment: Foundation framework has every thing doesn't means that we should not add a third party API to solve our problem. NSUTF8StringEncoding is not convert these character in proper format that's why he is facing problem at server side and this third party API can convert them in proper way and it's easy to encode them at server side.