# Character convert ion for Spanish characters in iPhone

Tags: iphone, web-services, encoding, character-encoding

I am writing an iPhone app, and I am consuming web services to get some info. This info is UTF-8 encoded, but some Spanish special characters are shown in a strange way (for instance, Ó is shown as &#211;).
How could I convert them?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you write the code of how you convert it? Gracias

Comment: The server side code is not mine. I simply use the response data in a connectionDidFinishLoading method: NSString *responseStringTemp = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; and erroneous characters are in responseStringTemp.

Answer (score 1):

Check this solution ,it may help:

[Spanish character encoding - iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403670/spanish-character-encoding-iphone)

Greetings from another spaniard!

Comment: And is there any alternative instead of converting every character into another? I mean, can we use something like stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString within a range (replacing '&#' and ';' and also converting 211 to Ó)? I am trying to to it in this way. I hope I will answer soon.